# CakePHP failed to open stream: Http request failed

Tags: php, rest, cakephp

I got a Problem with a Little bigger request from a REST API via Cake PHP.

Everything was working fine until I tried to read out a bigger ammount of Data.

It will be around 5000 records and when I try to Access These records I only get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Cake\Core\Exception\Exception' with
>   message
>   'fopen(https://test-api.appsolut.at:443/be14/crm/businesspartners?ApplicationKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! ' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\appsolut\api-appsolut\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Network\Http\Adapter\Stream.php:289
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\appsolut\api-appsolut\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Network\Http\Adapter\Stream.php(257):
>   Cake\Network\Http\Adapter\Stream->_open('https://test-ap...') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\appsolut\api-appsolut\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Network\Http\Adapter\Stream.php(81):
>   Cake\Network\Http\Adapter\Stream->_send(Object(Cake\Network\Http\Request))
>   2 C:\xampp\htdocs\appsolut\api-appsolut\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Network\Http\Client.php(360):
>   Cake\Network\Http\Adapter\Stream->send(Object(Cake\Network\Http\Request),
>   Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\appsolut\api-appsolut\v in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\appsolut\api-appsolut\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Network\Http\Adapter\Stream.php
>   on line 289

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Cheers

Comment: How large is the response you're trying to read?

Comment: check your max_execution_time

Comment: The Content Length will be: Content-Length: 2320524

Comment: I already increased the Max_execution_time.